# Error building Quantlib-SWIG python

Tags: python, centos7, quantlib

```
[idf@mail QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$ make -C Python
make: Entering directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings" /home/idf/anaconda2/bin/python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension
g++ -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/idf/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/include -c QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.o -Wno-unused -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings
cc1plus: warning: command line option \u2018-Wstrict-prototypes\u2019 is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 4
make[1]: *** [.build-stamp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/home/idf/Downloads/QuantLib-SWIG-1.7/Python'
[idf@mail QuantLib-SWIG-1.7]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler gave up with an internal error, i.e, it found itself in a situation in which it couldn't continue.  In principle the wrappers might have triggered a bug in the compiler, but that's unlikely.  It's more likely that it ran out of memory; the wrappers are massive, and you're adding a fairly aggressive optimization level (`-O2`) to the compilation flags.  I'd try decreasing the level to `-O0` or `-O1`, to see if that reduces the stress on the compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to upgrade the memory on my server to see if that helps.

Comment: That was the problem.